# IdHTTP stops on exception

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm doing a procedure to read multiple remote TXT files. Will work like this:
I have a TStringList with 3 (or more) URLs for TXT files, so I'm using IdHTTP to .Get the txt files and read them. But if the first TXT is offline or another exception, I want to go to the second and so on... I'm using this code:

```
  ValidTXT:= false;
  HTTP:= TIDHttp.Create(Nil);
  HTTP.ConnectTimeout:= 10000;
  Body:= TStringList.Create;
  HTTP.Request.UserAgent:= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; SLCC1';
  while ValidTXT = false do
    begin
      for i:= 0 to TXTs.Count - 1 do
        begin
          Body.Text:= HTTP.Get(TXTs.Strings[i]);
          Line:= Body.Strings[0];
          if pos('AmValid!', Line) > 0 then
            begin
              ValidTXT:= true;
```

so, if I get 'AmValid!' in first line of TXT file, it's a valid and I stop while. But if I don't get 'AmValid!' or get an exception, why I don't read the next TXT on StringList?

Comment: Your code sample seems incomplete; doesn't each `begin` need an `end` statement?

Comment: Yes I put only the important part... On this line: Body.Text:= HTTP.Get(TXTs.Strings[i]); if get one exception don't continue the for... why that?

Comment: Uncaught exceptions stop execution. This is normal. If you want to handle/ignore the exception, wrap it in a `try ... except ... end` block.